# What status should I use for Sentry performance in case of System Exception?

Tags: c#, performance, sentry

What performance status should I use for System Exceptions? so far I am only aware of HTTP request status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentry currrently doesn't have a good way to do that.

It's a bit too HTTP oriented. But the protocol is evolving so more values will come soon.